# How to add string to all list items in a ul using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, html-lists

I want to add the string of `&nbsp;` to all the list items of the ul when the button is pressed.

When the button is pressed the items should change from `List Item 01` to `1&nbsp;2&nbsp;3&nbsp;List Items 01`

Here is the code I have:

```
function addPadding() {
  var list = document.getElementById("ypnList").getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < list[i].length; i++) {
    list[i].id = "1&nbsp;2&nbsp;2&nbsp;" + list[i].id;
  }
}
```

```js
function addPadding() {
  var list = document.getElementById("ypnList").getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < list[i].length; i++) {
    list[i].id = "1&nbsp;2&nbsp;2&nbsp;" + list[i].id;

  }
}
```

```css
#ypnScrollbox {
  height: 8em;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid aqua;
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
}

#ypnScrollbox>ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

button {
  margin-top: 1em;
  background: wheat;
}
```

```html
<div id="ypnScrollbox">
  <ul id="ypnList" class="ypnList">
    <li>List Item 01</li>
    <li>List Item 02</li>
    <li>List Item 03</li>
    <li>List Item 04</li>
    <li>List Item 05</li>
    <li>List Item 06</li>
    <li>List Item 07</li>
    <li>List Item 08</li>
    <li>List Item 09</li>
    <li>List Item 10</li>
    <li>List Item 11</li>
    <li>List Item 12</li>
    <li>List Item 13</li>
    <li>List Item 14</li>
    <li>List Item 15</li>
    <li>List Item 16</li>
    <li>List Item 17</li>
    <li>List Item 18</li>
    <li>List Item 19</li>
    <li>List Item 20</li>
    <li>List Item 21</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br><br>
<button onclick="addPadding()">Add Padding</button>
```

Comment: the expected result is not clear

Comment: If you want to add text to the _content_ of an element, use `innerHTML += ...` However, the function name is "addPadding", so do you really want to add padding instead?

Comment: What is the end result that you want?

Comment: After editing, your question says you want to change _List Item_ to _List Items_, or is that a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this?

```js
function addPadding() {
  var list = document.querySelectorAll("li");
  for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i].innerHTML = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + list[i].innerHTML;

  }
}
```

```css
#ypnScrollbox {
  height: 8em;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid aqua;
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
}

#ypnScrollbox>ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

button {
  margin-top: 1em;
  background: wheat;
}

li {
  white-space:pre;
}
```

```html
<div id="ypnScrollbox">
  <ul id="ypnList" class="ypnList">
    <li>List Item 01</li>
    <li>List Item 02</li>
    <li>List Item 03</li>
    <li>List Item 04</li>
    <li>List Item 05</li>
    <li>List Item 06</li>
    <li>List Item 07</li>
    <li>List Item 08</li>
    <li>List Item 09</li>
    <li>List Item 10</li>
    <li>List Item 11</li>
    <li>List Item 12</li>
    <li>List Item 13</li>
    <li>List Item 14</li>
    <li>List Item 15</li>
    <li>List Item 16</li>
    <li>List Item 17</li>
    <li>List Item 18</li>
    <li>List Item 19</li>
    <li>List Item 20</li>
    <li>List Item 21</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br><br>
<button onclick="addPadding()">Add Padding</button>
```

Comment: why are we to use `.innerHTML`? when the li content is being stored in the array directly?

Comment: you should learn javascript.

Comment: Any good resources with simple explanations that you might suggest me?

Answer (score 1):

It is unsure whether you want to append something to an attribute of element or in its innerHTML. So I will cover both scenarios

**For InnerHTML**

```
function addPadding() {
  var list = document.getElementById("ypnList").getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i].innerHTML = list[i].innerHTML + "content I want to add";
  }
}
```

**For Attribute**

This will add some content in the `id` attribute, however it can be `class` or any other attribute

```
function addPadding() {
  var list = document.getElementById("ypnList").getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var attrValue = list[i].getAttribute('id');
    list[i].setAttribute('id', attrValue + "content I want to add")
  }
}
```

Comment: ```list[i].length``` must be changed to ```list.length```

Comment: correct, I copied the code question code, let me fix

Comment: fixed, will never copy and paste code again I swear